# Redirecting some of my website trafic to another URL, referrer based

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, web, redirect

My website is http://www.example.com

I would like to redirect 15% **of the Google/Bing incoming trafic** to my website, to a subdomain such as http://beta.example.com

I can use php, htaccess, ...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How are you calculating `15%`?

Comment: 15% is my own choice to redirect customers slowly, only some.The php code could redirect visits to the beta version every 15 visits. Or maybe randomly, a visitor has 15% odds to be redirected to the beta version.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if(strpos($referer, 'bing') !== false || strpos($referer, 'google') !== false) {

    if(rand(0, 100) < 15) {
        header('Location: http://beta.example.com/');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add an header with `Status: 302` or `Status: 303` to indicate it's not permanent.